# Ask gdb to do a pretty print when it catches a segfault

Tags: linux, gdb

I saw this on some BOF video,

[image]

It is gdb, just did a pretty-print when it catches segfault signal. I'm not sure how this is implemented, anyone knows?

Comment: Whoever hit on close, leave a message here at least!

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to do this is to install a SEGV handler that forks and executes "gdb -p" to attach to the dying process.

Comment: Yes this signal could be catched, so you mean this output is from the debuggee rather than the debugger?

Comment: No, the debuggee forks, then the fork'd child execs gdb to do the printing.